# How do I decrease the size of a font-awesome icon?

Tags: font-awesome, font-awesome-4

What is the best way to decrease the size of a font awesome icon.  There is a fa-3x, etc... to increase the size. Is there a class to decrease the size?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Font-Awesome icons, as the name suggests, are font-based. This means to decrease their size all you have to do is decrease their `font-size:`

```css
.fa {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: To add to his answer, almost everything you can do to a font you can do to the icons. Colors, sizes, spacing ect. ect. all get changed as if it were a font. Super simple!

Answer (score 36):

There are two Font Awesome classes to use if you need something simple: `fa-xs` and `fa-sm`.

The size equivalents are:

- **fa-xs:** `.75em`
- **fa-sm:** `.875em`

[Sizing Icons | Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/sizing-icons) (more information's here)

Comment: in v4 I do:<i class="fa fa-clone" style="font-size: 12px;"></i>. in v5: fa-xs/fa-sm

Answer (score 11):

Font-Awesome icon size modification:

1. "font-size" property in "style" attribute:

   ```
    <i class="fas fa-search" style="font-size: 25px;"></i>
   ```
2. "font-size" property in CSS stylesheet (like the accepted answer shows)

   ```
    .fa {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
   ```
3. HTML tags

   ```
    <small>
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    </small>
   ```
4. Using [Fontawesome classes](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/sizing-icons) so that the icons take a size relative to their parent elements:

   ```
    <i class="fas fa-search fa-sm"></i>

    <i class="fas fa-search fa-lg"></i>
   ```

Answer (score 3):

One way is your internal CSS class or use **default** Font Awesome class:

```
<i class="fas fa-camera fa-xs"></i>

<i class="fas fa-camera fa-sm"></i>

<i class="fas fa-camera fa-md"></i>

<i class="fas fa-camera fa-lg"></i>

<i class="fas fa-camera fa-2x"></i>
```

and keep going wit **fa-4x** and so one.

The Docs for smart use icons can be found here [Font Awesome Docs Sizing](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/sizing-icons) and **css** you could use will find documented there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Font-Awesome icons, as the name suggests, are font-based. This means to decrease their size all you have to do is decrease their `font-size`:

```
::before {
    font-size: 130px;
}
```