# Make Shiny icon smaller in Valuebox

Tags: r, shiny

My shiny icon is too big for my valuebox, I know how to change it bigger by adding "fa-3x", but could someone please tell me how to change it smaller? Thanks!

```
 valueBox(
      value = format(movie.avg1, digits = 3),
      subtitle = NULL,  
      icon = if (movie.avg1 >= 3) icon("thumbs-up") else icon("thumbs-down"),
      color = if (movie.avg1 >= 3) "aqua" else "red"
    )
```

[image]

Comment: @jsb just listed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `subtitle = HTML("&nbsp;")` instead of `NULL`. This will enter the invisible HTML character non-breaking space which will add the vertical space you need.

Comment: Note: This accepted solution fixes the issue of an icon breaking outside the bounds of a defined Shiny valueBox but does not adequately answer the question: "how to make the [icon] smaller".  If one truly wishes to make an icon inside the valueBox smaller, they should refer to the solution offered by GoGonzo below.

Answer (score 22):

### 1. Changing the size of all icons

Shiny `icon()` uses font-awesome in this case. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31992235/how-do-i-decrease-the-size-of-a-font-awesome-icon), decreasing size of icon can be done specifying `font-size` in css. To implement this in shiny just add this line in UI Body `tags$head( tags$style(HTML(".fa{font-size: 12px;}")))`

```r
library("shiny")
library("shinydashboard")

# header
header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "Changing the font size of valueBoxes", 
  titleWidth = 450
)

# sidebar
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE)

# body
body <- dashboardBody(
  tags$head( 
    tags$style(HTML(".fa{font-size: 12px;}"))
  ),
  valueBox(
    value = "3.94",
    subtitle = NULL,  
    icon = icon("thumbs-up")
  )
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body), 
  server = function(input, output){}
)
```

[image]

### 2. Changing the size of a single element

If one wants to change size of one element instead of all elements with the same class (`.fa` in this case), use `tags$i(class = "fas fa-thumbs-down", style="font-size: 12px")` instead of `icon()`. Where appropriate class can be found [in font awesome docs](https://fontawesome.com/icons/thumbs-up).

```r
library("shiny")
library("shinydashboard")

header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "Changing the font size of valueBoxes", 
  titleWidth = 450
)
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE)
body <- dashboardBody(
  valueBox(
    value = "3.94",
    subtitle = NULL,  
    icon = tags$i(class = "fas fa-thumbs-down", style="font-size: 12px")
  ),
  valueBox(
    value = "5.00",
    subtitle = NULL,  
    icon = tags$i(class = "fas fa-thumbs-up", style="font-size: 24px; color: white")
  )
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body), 
  server = function(input, output){}
)
```

[image]